# Using POST instead of GET in my URL to get data into / from CakePHP, maybe JQuery?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, post, get

---

### EDITS

```
         echo "<img  class='imageTagId' width='100' height='100'>";
```

This is the line of PHP code in my view thats going to hold the logo file.

And this is the code you gave me, edited to make it work with my function! However, this ws working friday night (I sure it was!!) now its not!!

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/viewlogo",
                data: {
                    userid     : <?php echo $USER_ID ?>
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $(".imageTagId").attr('src', result);
                }
            });
        });
```

However if I go back to my GET url then it works,

```
   echo "<img class='imageTagId' width='100' height='100' src='/viewlogo?userid=" . $USER_ID ."'
```

That line of code works fine!! I am not sure what I have changed else where that might have changed this from working to not working.

But it loads (or at lest tries to load) a page

```
 <img class="imageTagId" width="100" height="100" src="&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; &lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt; ...... more....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Glenn.

---

OLD POST

I am using CakePHP as a based to build a site that uploads and then gets the logo files for the selected user. These files are saved outside of Cakes WEBROOT folder. This is all working without any issues at all. But I am using GET URL params to set data for the selected user to pull down the logo files.

It looks like ::

```
/DATAPATH?thisiswork=logos$userid=XX
```

What I want is to able to use POST to pass these vars onto the controller. I will also state that this path is loaded into a img tag and loads the logo right into my view.

Any ideas?

I was looking at using JQuery's $.ajax POST call but I am not sure if they are right or will work>

Many Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery's $.ajax POST or GET is good for returning either a string or serialized data like XML or JSON. The only use I could see it having in your case is if you need the parameters to create the image in the first place, then you could have it return the url of the newly created logo image:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DATAPATH",
    data: {
        thisiswork : logos, 
        userid     : XX
    },
    success: function(result){
        //ajax callback function, populate the result in the image tag's src attribute.
        $("#imageTagId").attr('src', result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Three possibilities: 1. you're seeing a php server error which is making the page return the default 500 (Internal Server Error) page. 2. Try putting "header("Content-Type: text/plain");" in the php file that you're making the ajax call to. It looks like the file thinks it's supposed to return a full html page when you just want it to return the url string without any overhead. 3. Also verify that there isn't any text or html outside of your <?php ?> tags and that the only output is from an "echo $url;" somewhere. The problem is definitely in the php file somewhere, not your javascript or html